# Can the swarmplot of seaborn adjust the marker shape of points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, seaborn

1. I used the swarmplot function in seaborn to plot the category scatter plot. But I have two types of points in each category. So I wish can set different types of points into different markers. 
   **Can the swarmplot of seaborn adjust the marker shape of points? Or I can use other tools**
2. I only found the parameter markers size can be adjusted in the document of the swarmplot. And I tried to use hue. But when I use hue, all categories represent same color. That is not my idea.

3.

```
# plot the manhattan map
snsplt =sns.swarmplot(x=scale,y=distance,marker='o')
plt.tick_params(labelsize=12)
# plot the significant line


bin = np.arange(-0.2,5.2,0.2)
y = np.full((len(bin),),distance[p_minsignIndex])
snsplt = sns.lineplot(x=bin,y=y)
plt.show()
```

[The image is my draft.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xMIe.png)

**I wish the circles above the line are filled circles and the circles below the line are hollow circles.**

Comment: How about just putting an `x` or something inside each circle of the swarm plot?

Comment: can you check you code above.. there seems to be something missing in the sns.swamplot call..

Comment: The well known problem with swarm plots is that where the points appear in the plot, and the general structure of the plot, depends on the size of the circles (because that determines how they pack). This problem is much more difficult for non-circular shapes, and, basically, nobody uses non-circular shapes for this reason. It would be easy find the positions of all the circles, and then replace the shapes, but it would look weird. So you need to specify what you want here. Maybe draw a picture by hand and convince us that you really want what you've asked for.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have updated the code and my draft image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the plots you show, it seems that you have two categories happening at the same time:
1) the position along the axis indicates one category -- I'll call this `cat1`; and,
2) variation within each category and this is what you want to show by the marker -- I'll call this `cat2`.

By far, the easiest ways to show these two categories together is to use the tools given to you by seaborn to do this.  Specifically, in your plots, you are identifying `cat1` in two different ways: first by its position along the x-axis, and second by the color.  So the idea is to use the position for `cat1` and the color for `cat2`. Also, you mention in the comments below that you want to use the markers to show a statistical significance, so I chose a palette that does that well.  Here's an example taken from the seaborn docs, but modified to show a significance threshold (as you requested):

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

tips['bigness'] = np.where(tips['total_bill']>15, 'big', 'small')
sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="bigness", data=tips, palette="Paired", hue_order=["small", "big"])
```

[image]

Comment: @StevenHill: this is the easy and built-in approach for swarm plots on seaborn.  It's a good approach.  If, in looking it over you have a compelling reason to do the circle outline, I'd be interested to hear it.  It seems more difficult to read to me -- just a little dot in the center of each circle that's different?  It seems the colors are more clear, even for grayscale. Changing the shape, or the circle outline, isn't super difficult, but it takes some effort to find an enumerate and change the circles.

Comment: Thank you for listening and your answer. The points above the line are statistically significant. I try to emphasize the importance of the points by whether the point is solid. Besides, it's interesting for me to know those tricks. But you are right, the effect of this display method may not be better.

Comment: @StevenHill: I've changed the colors of the plot to reflect "significance" by de-emphasizing using a pale color, and taking advantage of the fact that seaborn has a palette for this called "Paired". (Although it's harder to do in seaborn than matplotlib, it is possible to edit each symbol directly, but it's easier and better -- for re-use and sharing etc -- if you can avoid it. Plus, I think this looks good.)

Comment: @StevenHill: To fulfill your curiosity of how the markers can be edited, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52909761/102302) from SO. Note, though, that unless you've seen the initial swarm plot, it's not *a priori* obvious what is establishing the locations (eg, squares overlab, triagles have lots of space, etc), and overall these are difficult to read. Also, if you're new to seaborn/matplotlib, it's worth noting too that this type of thing (editing the individual artists) is more difficult in seaborn than matplotlib.